# A basic question about elliptic pde

Tags: elliptic-pde

I have (hopefully) a rather basic question about smooth elliptic partial differential
equations.

Let $L$ be a linear elliptic differential operator with polynomial coefficients in $\mathbb{R}^n, n>1.$ Let $u\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be such that it has compact support
and $L(u)$ is supported on a finite set (as a distribution). Then is $u$ necessarily 0?
I (naively) hope that the answer is yes, and perhaps could be proved by using some known
asymptotics of the fundamental solution of $L$ near the support of $u.$ Any suggestions or references will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify? If $u$ has compact support, then isn’t $Lu$ always a compactly supported distribution?

Comment: Right, but question is if $Lu$ can have a support that is a finite set, which is much stronger that having a compact support.

Comment: you probably want $n > 1$, else the tent function $\psi$ has $\psi''$ supported at exactly three points. // A minor nitpick about your phrasing: since your conclusion is $u \equiv 0$ a fortieri you cannot have $L(u)$ with non-empty support. Maybe better to say that $\mathrm{supp} L(u)$ is contained in a finite set.

Comment: Anyway: to your question, you maybe able to get what you want using unique continuation.

Comment: Thanks, I do have that n>1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **Yes** and is a consequence of Holmgren's uniqueness Theorem. See for instance [Theorem 1.1.4 in this text.](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~nicolas.lerner/m2carl.pdf). The ellipticity serves here to ensure that there does not exist a characteristic hypersurface. Applying HUT, you obtain that $u\equiv0$ over the connected component of the complement of the support of $Lu$. In your case, this means $u\equiv0$ away from a finite set, but since $u\in L^\infty$, this is $u=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!